# Operation failed addTestResultLink

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I'm migrating from an on-premise TFS 2010 to VSO. I get multiple of the following error:

> OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed addTestResultLink. Server Error : Error occured while adding link caused by:TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save from    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags saveFlags)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.Save()
>      at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSTestResultClient.addTestResultLink(String sourceWorkItemId, Int32 targetWorkItemId, String linkType, String comment, String addedByUser) in e:\OVSMUBranch\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSTestResultUtility.cs:line 1306

**Screenshot:**

[image: OpsHub failure log]

---

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please send us the logs from location "c:/OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility/logs" and version of the migration utility which you are using at ovsmu@opshub.com

Comment: Logs have been sent.